# Consul template, consul and HaProxy setup with springboot applications in docker containers

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, consul

Can someone tell me how to configure HaProxy config and consul-template to fill the config file automatically? How do we configure consul-template? How do the HaProxy config file and consul-template communicate? Any examples available would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this HAProxy blog post will help you:
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/building-a-service-mesh-with-haproxy-and-consul/